# Replace numbers not in parentheses?

Tags: bash, replace, awk, sed, grep

I have a file containing some numbers and letters, e.g.:

Input:

```
9(9)S99
D9(9)L9(9)
G999N9(9)
99C99
```

I need to replace all numbers(in this case 9) by **X** except those inside parentheses, e.g.:

Output:

```
X(9)SXX
DX(9)LX(9)
GXXXNX(9)
XXCXX
```

Is that posible in bash using sed, grep or awk?
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using GNU awk for multi-char RS:

```
$ cat file                                                         
9(9)S99
D9(999)L9(9)
G999N9(9)
99C99

$ gawk -v RS='[()]' '{ORS=RT} NR%2{gsub(/[[:digit:]]/,"X")} 1' file
X(9)SXX
DX(999)LX(9)
GXXXNX(9)
XXCXX
```

That above assumes your parens always come in un-nested pairs, e.g. you cannot have `(( ... )`

Comment: It works very well, even if there are 4+ numbers inside parentheses it wont change them, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Through perl,

```
$ perl -pe 's/(?<!\()9/X/g' file
X(9)SXX
DX(9)LX(9)
GXXXNX(9)
XXCXX
```

Comment: @lihao how about this `perl -pe 's/(?<=\()9(?=9)|(?<=9)9(?=\))|(?<!\()9(?!\))/X/g' file`?

Comment: @AvinashRaj it´s changing all numbers, also I noticed that if you got (9)+, I mean (999) or (9999) it will leave only 1st and last number and will change rest.

Comment: That's what im saying: (99999999) -> (XXXXXXXX) and it should leave 9.

Comment: @Flap who said this? OP don't want to match a single 9 within parenthesis that is `(9)` only. It's accepted by the OP, i donno what's your actual problem is.

Comment: @AvinashRaj - Flap IS the OP, he's unfortunately clarifying his requirements in comments instead of editing his question.

Comment: @Avinash Raj, it's too complex, you can do: perl -pe 's/(\(\d\))|(\d)/$1 or "X"/eg' file. if OP wants to keep (999) as is, just adjust the first \d to \d+.

Comment: @EdMorton failed to see who is OP :-)